# Command line arguments validation with GetOpts and mandatory parameters

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-14.04, getopts

I'm creating a basic script that should take 3 mandatory command line options and each one must be followed by a value. Like this:

```
$ myscript.sh -u <username> -p <password> -f <hosts.txt>
```

I'm trying to make sure the user is passing those exact 3 options and their values and nothing else, otherwise I want to print the usage message and exit.

I've been reading on `getopts` and came up with this:

```
usage () { echo "Usage : $0 -u <username> -p <password> -f <hostsFile>"; }

if [ $# -ne 6 ]
then
        usage
        exit 1
fi

while getopts u:p:f: opt ; do
   case $opt in
      u) USER_NAME=$OPTARG ;;
      p) USER_PASSWORD=$OPTARG ;;
      f) HOSTS_FILE=$OPTARG ;;
      *) usage; exit 1;;
   esac
done

echo "USERNAME: $USER_NAME"
echo "PASS: $USER_PASSWORD"
echo "FILE: $HOSTS_FILE"
```

I was hoping that if I do not pass any of my 3 "mandatory" options (i.e: -u -p -f) Optargs validation would catch that via the "`*)`" case. While that is true for other options such "-a","-b", etc..  does not seem to be the case in this particular case:

```
$ myscript.sh 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Getops does not treat that as invalid input and the script moves on executing the `echo` commands showing 3 empty variables.

How can I capture the input above as being invalid as it is not in the form of:

```
$ myscript.sh -u <username> -p <password> -f <hosts.txt>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getopts` has no concept of "mandatory" options.  The colons in `u:p:f:` mean that, if one of those options happens to be supplied, then an argument to that option is mandatory.  The option-argument pairs, however, are always optional.

You can require that the user provide all three though with code such as:

```
if [ ! "$USER_NAME" ] || [ ! "$USER_PASSWORD" ] || [ ! "$HOSTS_FILE" ]
then
    usage
    exit 1
fi
```

Place this code after the `while getopts` loop.

#### The Role of `*)`

> I was hoping that if I do not pass any of my 3 "mandatory" options (i.e: -u -p -f) Optargs validation would catch that via the "*)" case.

The `*)` case is executed only if an option *other than* `-u`, `-p`, or `-f` is supplied.  Thus, if someone supplied, for example a `-z` argument, then that case would run.

Comment: Arguments to options that take them are mandatory but supplying the options themselves are not.

Comment: @EtanReisner Good point.  I revised the answer to clarify that arguments can be mandatory for a given option, but that the option-argument pair is still optional.

Comment: Thanks @John1024, that was the piece I was missing and now I've consolidated the argument validation into a single "if" statement like this: if [ $# -ne 6 ] || [ ! "$USER_NAME" ] || [ ! "$USER_PASSWORD" ] || [ ! "$HOSTS_FILE" ]